# Sleep Lua script while letting the master program continue

Tags: lua, sleep, wait

I am programming a plugin to a program that has integrated Lua scripting, and need to have my script check a condition every x seconds.

I have tried different methods of "sleeping" the Lua script, but all my methods so far also hang/pause the main program.

Is there a way to have my Lua script run every x seconds without pausing the master program.

Comment: Only if the master program gives you a way to do that via timer/callback/etc.. You can't do this on your own.

Comment: You could look at [coroutines](http://www.lua.org/pil/9.1.html), but the embedding program would still need to respect the `yield`/`resume` pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use os.time() and os.difftime():

```
local waitTime = 3
if t1 == nil then t1 = os.time() end

--Check
if math.floor(os.difftime(os.time(),t1)) == waitTime then
    t1 = os.time()
    -- Do stuff
end
```

This runs your code every 3 seconds.

Comment: Lua doesn't provide a native method to _delay_ execution, so if you run that in a loop it will consume 100% of your cpu.

Comment: Why it consumes a lot amount of cpu?

Comment: You have to keep checking until 3 seconds have elapsed, otherwise the code you're waiting for will never actually be run. Without using a mechanism to _sleep_, that code must run repeatedly in a loop. If that loop is internal to lua it will just grind until the clock hits the right value. If, however, the code is called from an external event loop, it would fail if `difftime` happens to be 4 by the next time the loop ran.